# Autocomplete not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, animation, autocomplete

Master page HTML :

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="PMS.master.vb" Inherits="PMS.PMS" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register Src="~/Resources/UControl/UserControlMenu.ascx" TagName="UserControlMenu" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <link href="Resources/CSS/PostCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100%">
                            <!--Header-->
                            <table border="0" background="Resources/Images/bnrCol.jpg"cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="Left" >
                                        <img src="Resources/Images/BnrLeft.jpg"  alt="">
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="Right">
                                        <img src="Resources/Images/BnrRight.jpg"  alt="">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--Menu-->
                                     <uc1:UserControlMenu ID="UserControlMenu1" runat="server" />       


                            <!--Content-->
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#EBEBE2" width="100%">
                                        <center>
                                            <%--body+menu here --%>
                                            <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>


                                                    <td bgcolor="white"  width="100%" valign="top">
                                                        <%--body here --%>
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td  rowspan="2">
                                                                    &nbsp;
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td valign="top">
                                                                    <div>
                                                                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="BodyContent" runat="server">
                                                                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </center>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!--Footer-->
                            <%-- <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#A1BBCA" height="23" align="center">
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="lblCaptionSmall" ></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>--%>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Content HTML Code (the page):

```
<%@ Page  Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/PMS.Master"
    CodeBehind="CreateStatement.aspx.vb" Inherits="PMS.CreateStatement" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent" runat="server">

            <asp:TextBox CssClass="lblCaption" ID="MainGovSource" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
                Width="300px" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
            <div id="divAutoComp">
            </div>
            <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" MinimumPrefixLength="1"
                ServiceMethod="GetOfficialMainCustomer" ServicePath="~/AutoComplete.asmx" TargetControlID="MainGovSource"
                BehaviorID="AutoCompleteExtender1" EnableCaching="false" Enabled="True" CompletionSetCount="40"
                CompletionListElementID="divAutoComp" CompletionInterval="1">
                <Animations>
                    <OnShow>
                        <Sequence>
                            <%-- Make the completion list transparent and then show it --%>
                            <OpacityAction Opacity="0" />
                            <HideAction Visible="true" />

                            <%--Cache the original size of the completion list the first time
                                the animation is played and then set it to zero --%>
                            <ScriptAction Script="
                                // Cache the size and setup the initial size
                                var behavior = $find('AutoCompleteEx');
                                if (!behavior._height) {
                                    var target = behavior.get_completionList();
                                    behavior._height = target.offsetHeight - 2;
                                    target.style.height = '0px';
                                }" />

                            <%-- Expand from 0px to the appropriate size while fading in --%>
                            <Parallel Duration=".4">
                                <FadeIn />
                                <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValue="0" EndValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx')._height" />
                            </Parallel>
                        </Sequence>
                    </OnShow>
                    <OnHide>
                        <%-- Collapse down to 0px and fade out --%>
                        <Parallel Duration=".4">
                            <FadeOut />
                            <Length PropertyKey="height" StartValueScript="$find('AutoCompleteEx')._height" EndValue="0" />
                        </Parallel>
                    </OnHide>
                </Animations>
            </asp:AutoCompleteExtender> 

</asp:Content>
```

AutoComplete.asmx

VB Code:

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Collections
Imports PMS.Access
Imports PMS.Common
Imports PMS.Business

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class AutoComplete
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService


    Public Sub AutoComplete()

    End Sub


    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Function GetOfficialMainCustomer(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer) As String()

        '--------------
        Dim objCustomersBusinessController As New Business.CustomersBusinessController
        Dim dsCustomers As New DSCustomer
        dsCustomers = objCustomersBusinessController.LoadMainGoverment(-1)


        dsCustomers.Customers.ToList()

        Dim arrList() As DSCustomer.CustomersRow
        arrList = dsCustomers.Customers.Select("CustomerName like '%" & prefixText & "%'")

        Return arrList.Where(Function(c) c.CustomerName.ToLower().Contains(prefixText.ToLower())).[Select](Function(p) p.CustomerName).Take(400).ToArray()



    End Function


End Class
```

CustomersBusinessController.vb

```
Imports PMS.Access
Imports PMS.Common
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System

Public Class CustomersBusinessController
    Inherits BusinessController

    Dim objCustomersAccessController As CustomersAccessController = New CustomersAccessController

    Public Function LoadMainGoverment(ByVal CustomerID As Integer) As DSCustomer

        Return objCustomersAccessController.LoadMainGoverment(CustomerID)

    End Function


End Class
```

CSS :

```
.autocomplete_completionListElement 
{ 
visibility : hidden;
margin : 0px!important;
background-color : inherit;
color : windowtext;
border : buttonshadow;
border-width : 1px;
border-style : solid;
cursor : 'default';
overflow : auto;
height : 100px;
text-align : left; 
list-style-type : none;
}

/* AutoComplete highlighted item */

.autocomplete_highlightedListItem
{
background-color: #ffff99;
color: black;
padding: 1px;
}

/* AutoComplete item */

.autocomplete_listItem 
{
background-color : window;
color : windowtext;
padding : 1px;
}

/*trial for the test*/

.ContextMenuPanel 
{
border: 1px solid #868686;
z-index: 1000;
background: url(images/menu-bg.gif) repeat-y 0 0 #FAFAFA;
cursor: default;
padding: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
font-size: 11px;
}

.ContextMenuBreak
{
margin:1px 1px 1px 32px;
padding:0;
height:1px;
overflow:hidden;
display:block;
border-top: 1px solid #C5C5C5; 
}

a.ContextMenuItem
{
margin: 1px 0 1px 0;
display: block;
color: #003399;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer; 
padding: 4px 19px 4px 33px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

a.ContextMenuItem-Selected
{
font-weight: bold;
}

a.ContextMenuItem:hover
{
background-color: #FFE6A0;
color: #003399;
border: 1px solid #D2B47A;
padding: 3px 18px 3px 32px;
}
```

Note : I am using the AJAX Version 4.1.51116.0

and

I have seen [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1161298.aspx/1) and [that](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)

and tried to work it out ... but nothing is going on ..So Whats Up?

HELP PLEASE .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT have been solved Thank GOD... special thanks to  @Vinod and @Neha

The problem was in `AutoComplete.asmx`

```
<%@ WebService Language="vb" CodeBehind="AutoComplete.asmx.vb" Class="attend.AutoComplete" %>
```

---

`Class="attend.AutoComplete"` ... attend is the project that i took AutoComplete.asmx  and my

project name is PMS .. I changed it to :

```
<%@ WebService Language="vb" CodeBehind="AutoComplete.asmx.vb" Class="PMS.AutoComplete" %>
```

and it is working fine now ..

Thanks again guys ..@Vinod and @Neha

Answer (score 2):

web service code in c# try it in vb

```
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Documents and Settings\\Vinu\\My Documents\\Northwind.mdb");
    String instr = prefixText + "%";
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select ContactName from Customers where ContactName like '"+instr+"'", conn);

    DataTable dt=new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    List<string> items = new List<string>(count);
    for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
                    items.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString());
    }

    return items.ToArray();
}
```